# MLP 32 hidden units are there so how many total parameters,including weights and biases are present?

Tags: deep-learning

We have a dataset containing 90,000 black and white images of objects that are 64 by 64 pixels in size. Our goal is to classify the images into three classes: animals, vehicles and a class that represents everything else.

If this MLP contains one hidden layer containing 32 units, how many total parameters, including weights and biases, are in the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the MLP that you want to create. In the first "dense_1" layer contains 131104 
parameters which comes from `64*64*32 + 32(bias) = 131104`. In the second layer "dense_2" contains 33 params which come from `32 + 1(bias) = 33`. The total trainable parameter number is `131,137`.

[image]